# How to fix "Dillo HTTPS: Missing issuer certificate!"?

Tags: openssl, certificates, browser, notifications

I use the Dillo browser and usually when I open a new website I get the following error message:

> **Dillo HTTPS: Missing issuer certificate!**
>
> Unable to get local issuer certificate. The issuer certificate of an untrusted certificate cannot be found.

Sometimes I get this error 3 times in a row while opening bigger websites like Twitter.

If I click *Continue* the page will load normally.

I've got this problem with Dillo 3.0.5 on FreeBSD 10.3 powerpc (installed from ports) and FreeBSD 10.3 i386 (installed using pkg).

This message however doesn't pop up on Dillo version 3.0.4 on BunsenLabs Linux (Hydrogen) i386.

The source code with this message is available here: https://fossies.org/linux/dillo/dpi/https.c

I thought it might be related to [Curl - SSL certificate problem](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/57219/) but I've checked the options I installed curl with and `CA_BUNDLE` is on.

Comment: Possibly related: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/33058/

Answer (score 1):

This question is old and this is not a real answer, but I had the same problem. In dpi/https.c, I commented out the dialogue box code after

```
    case X509_V_ERR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN:
```

and then changed

```
    response_number = dialogue_get_answer_number();
```

to

```
    response_number = 1;
```

I'm sure this is terrible for some reason, but I would always agree with the dialogue box anyway.